# Kubernetes install kafka and kafka don`t connect the zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, bitnami-kafka

I am installing kafka in my computer. The Linux cluster I set up is on my Apple computer with an M1 chip. I have 4 yaml files about this.

zookeeper-svc.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zoo1
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-1
spec:
  ports:
    - name: client
      port: 2181
      protocol: TCP
    - name: follower
      port: 2888
      protocol: TCP
    - name: leader
      port: 3888
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: zookeeper-1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zoo2
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-2
spec:
  ports:
    - name: client
      port: 2181
      protocol: TCP
    - name: follower
      port: 2888
      protocol: TCP
    - name: leader
      port: 3888
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: zookeeper-2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zoo3
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-3
spec:
  ports:
    - name: client
      port: 2181
      protocol: TCP
    - name: follower
      port: 2888
      protocol: TCP
    - name: leader
      port: 3888
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: zookeeper-3
```

zookeeper-dep.yaml

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-1
      name: zookeeper-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper-1
        name: zookeeper-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zoo1
          image: zookeeper:3.6.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
              value: zoo1
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_2
              value: zoo2
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_3
              value: zoo3
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-deployment-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-2
      name: zookeeper-2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper-2
        name: zookeeper-2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zoo2
          image: zookeeper:3.6.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: "2"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
              value: zoo1
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_2
              value: zoo2
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_3
              value: zoo3
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-deployment-3
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-3
      name: zookeeper-3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper-3
        name: zookeeper-3
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zoo3
          image: zookeeper:3.6.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_ID
              value: "3"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1
              value: zoo1
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_2
              value: zoo2
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_3
              value: zoo3
```

3.kafka-svc.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service-1
  labels:
    app: kafka-service-1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      name: kafka-service-1
      targetPort: 9092
      nodePort: 30901
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka-service-1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service-2
  labels:
    app: kafka-service-2
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      name: kafka-service-2
      targetPort: 9092
      nodePort: 30902
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka-service-2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service-3
  labels:
    app: kafka-service-3
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      name: kafka-service-3
      targetPort: 9092
      nodePort: 30903
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka-service-3
```

kafka-dep.yaml

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: app/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kafka-service-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kafka-service-1
        app: kafka-service-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-1
          image:  bitnami/kafka:3.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
              value: "9092"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: [kafka-service1的clusterIP]
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
              value: mytopic:2:1
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: app/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-deployment-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kafka-service-2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kafka-service-2
        app: kafka-service-2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-2
          image:  bitnami/kafka:3.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
              value: "9092"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: [kafka-service2的clusterIP]
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "2"
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: app/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-deployment-3
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kafka-service-3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kafka-service-3
        app: kafka-service-3
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-3
          image:  bitnami/kafka:3.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
              value: "9092"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: [kafka-service3的clusterIP]
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "3"
```

So, this is all files about my project! And I will provide some picture about it.

[image]

As you see, zookeeper is running Correctly.

[image]

Next is logs information in kafka pods.

```
kafka 15:58:59.00 
kafka 15:58:59.00 Welcome to the Bitnami kafka container
kafka 15:58:59.00 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
kafka 15:58:59.00 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
kafka 15:58:59.00 
kafka 15:58:59.00 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka setup **
kafka 15:58:59.03 WARN  ==> The KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PROTOCOL environment variable does not configure SASL and/or SSL, this setting is not recommended for production environments.
/opt/bitnami/scripts/libkafka.sh: line 377: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: unbound variable
kafka 15:58:59.04 WARN  ==> Kafka has been configured with a PLAINTEXT listener, this setting is not recommended for production environments.
kafka 15:58:59.04 INFO  ==> Initializing Kafka...
kafka 15:58:59.04 INFO  ==> No injected configuration files found, creating default config files
/opt/bitnami/scripts/libkafka.sh: line 973: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: unbound variable
kafka 15:58:59.07 INFO  ==> ** Kafka setup finished! **
kafka 15:58:59.08 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka **
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,675] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,852] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,914] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,915] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,915] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,934] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.4--d65253dcf68e9097c6e95a126463fd5fdeb4521c, built on 12/18/2022 18:10 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:host.name=kafka-deployment-1-9ffd5645d-h8mf6 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:java.version=17.0.8 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=BellSoft (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:java.home=/opt/bitnami/java (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.13.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.6.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.13.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.29.2-GA.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.39.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.39.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.39.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.39.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.39.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.39.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jline-3.22.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jose4j-0.9.3.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-group-coordinator-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-metadata-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-raft-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-server-common-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-shell-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-storage-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-storage-api-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.8.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-4.1.12.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/reload4j-1.2.25.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-7.1.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.10.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.12-1.0.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.15.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.15.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/swagger-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/trogdor-3.4.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.6.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.6.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:os.arch=aarch64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:os.version=5.11.12-300.el7.aarch64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:user.name=? (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:user.home=? (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=1014MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,939] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,940] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181 sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@7ca33c24 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,943] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,946] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-08-20 15:58:59,947] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-08-20 15:59:17,954] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-08-20 15:59:19,978] ERROR Unable to resolve address: zoo2/<unresolved>:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider)
java.net.UnknownHostException: zoo2: Temporary failure in name resolution
 at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:934)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1543)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1385)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1306)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider$1.getAllByName(StaticHostProvider.java:88)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.resolve(StaticHostProvider.java:141)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.next(StaticHostProvider.java:368)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1208)
[2023-08-20 15:59:19,988] INFO Opening socket connection to server zoo2/<unresolved>:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-08-20 15:59:19,993] ERROR Unable to open socket to zoo2/<unresolved>:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,099] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,103] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,105] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
 at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:254)
 at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:250)
 at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:108)
 at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:2262)
 at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.createZkClient(KafkaZkClient.scala:2354)
 at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:595)
 at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:214)
 at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:115)
 at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,105] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,106] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,111] INFO App info kafka.server for 1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,112] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,112] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
 at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:254)
 at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:250)
 at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:108)
 at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:2262)
 at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.createZkClient(KafkaZkClient.scala:2354)
 at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:595)
 at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:214)
 at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:115)
 at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2023-08-20 15:59:20,113] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: Please avoid excessive headers and bold in the question.